# How to resolve CORS error on website hosted in IIS?

Tags: .net-core, iis, cors

We have two websites hosted on IIS on our server - one is in http://localhost:80/ with react frontend and .NET apis
and the other is in http://localhost:81/ with react frontend and it makes use of the apis in the previous website.

We are facing CORS errors when api call is made from http://localhost:81/ like below,

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost/api/Website/Login' from
> origin 'http://localhost:81' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response
> to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource.

GET method calls are going through without any problems. Only the POST method calls fail with this message.
We have included UseCors on the backend of the website http://localhost:80/ as shown below

```
          services.AddCors(opt =>
          {
              opt.AddPolicy("CORSPolicy", policy =>
              {
                  policy.AllowAnyHeader()
                    .WithMethods("PUT, POST, GET, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS")
                    .WithOrigins("http://localhost:81", "http://<<ip>>:81");
              });
          }
          );
```

and

```
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseDefaultFiles();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseCors("CORSPolicy");
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();
```

Still it does not work. Tried the same kind of setup on my local machine and it works fine without any CORS errors. But on server it does not.

We have been trying to find a solution for this for a few days now, but so far no break through. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution for this. We had missed the OPTIONS verb in our web.config file. So added that and made little more changes to the above code as follows

```
.WithHeaders("Origin", "Accept", "X-Requested-With", "Content-Type")
.WithMethods("PUT", "POST", "GET", "DELETE", "OPTIONS")
```

Comment: If you check out IIS CORS module, you will notice many can be handled by IIS instead, https://blogs.iis.net/iisteam/getting-started-with-the-iis-cors-module

Comment: Tried adding this
<cors enabled="true">
      <add origin="http://localhost:81">
        <allowMethods>
            <add method="GET" />
            <add method="HEAD" />
            <add method="POST" />
            <add method="PUT" /> 
            <add method="DELETE" />
        </allowMethods>
      </add>
      <add origin="http://<<ip>>:81">
        <allowMethods>
            <add method="GET" />
            <add method="HEAD" />
            <add method="POST" />
            <add method="PUT" />

Comment: <add method="DELETE" />
</allowMethods>
      </add>
    </cors>
But it does not work.